# How to return in MySQL GROUP BY the first record by DATE?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have in the table 30 records with the same Title but different Ids and dates each one. How to return in the query de most recent by date?

The table looks like this:

```
Id - Title - Date
-----------------
1 - africa - 2012-11-27
2 - africa - 2012-11-26
3 - africa - 2012-11-25
```

I need a query that returns the record which Id is 3, that is the most recent by the date. All I've tried until now using GROUP BY is only returning the record wich Id is 1. How can I do that?

Comment: Record `id=1` is more "recent" than `id=3`, if the `Date` column is anything to go by?

Comment: The most recent record is the one with Id 1 so maybe your query is returning the correct result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to get the first record but that is not the *recent*. The idea behind the subquery is that it gets the first date for each title and joined it against itself provided that it match the title and the date.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  title, MIN(DATE) minDate
            FROM tableName
            GROUP BY title
        ) b ON a.title = b.title AND
                a.date = b.maxDate
```

Answer (score 3):

You want the [groupwise maximum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html):

```
SELECT * FROM my_table NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT   Title, MAX(Date) Date
  FROM     my_table
  GROUP BY Title
) t
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/52a73/1/0).

If you define "*most recent*" by that with the highest `id`, rather than that with the latest `Date`:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT   Title, MAX(id) id
  FROM     my_table
  GROUP BY Title
) t
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/52a73/2/0).

Comment: This won't return the id of the most recent record with each title, which I assume is what the OP wants.

Comment: @AlexeyFeldgendler: Yes, it will.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something easy like that

```
SELECT
Id as Id,
MAX(Date) as Date
FROM NameOfYourTable 
GROUP BY Id
```